# How to display product category's individual product list in shop page?

Tags: wp-admin

I want to display each product category's sub products list in the shop page. Actually now in my shop page was displaying the whole list of products. But when ever i click on the list of sub category menu the control was automatically goes to the home page of that site. And i can understand that there is no code error. When i add 2 categories followed by the 4 pre_category in the admin part this problem is occur. So may be its WP-ADMIN settings problem.

```
I done this site by using woocommerce plugin.

Can u pls help me whats the problem...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add short codes for separate category.
For example: [product_category category="cat name goes..."] 
You can add many categories, as you want.

Comment: Hi, actually my problem is when i click on each product category it was redirect towards the home page as default instead of listing that particular category product list. I already used this short codes  [product_category category="cat name goes..."] for displaying each product category...

Comment: I done it, just upload the query.php in the wp-includes folder from new wordpress version. thank you